# How to get "scrollTop"-value of FB.Canvas.getPageInfo

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

So far I can alert the "scrollTop"-value of "[FB.Canvas.getPageInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/)":

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
      function(info) {
          alert('scrollTop: ' + info.scrollTop);
      }
  );
```

Now I would like to use this value in one of my functions, but I don't know how.
The following is not working:

```
function test() {
    var fbScrollTop = FB.Canvas.getPageInfo();
    alert(fbScrollTop);
}
```

How can I access the the value?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's useful yet.
But now I can center my divs in my facebook app.
Here is the function:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    var temp = this;
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
            $(temp).css("position","absolute");
            $(temp).css("top", Math.max(0, ((info.clientHeight - $(temp).outerHeight()) / 2) + info.scrollTop) + "px");
            $(temp).css("left", Math.max(0, ((info.clientWidth - $(temp).outerWidth()) / 2) + info.scrollLeft) + "px");
        }
    );

    return this;
}
```

And I use like that:

```
var loading = $("#loading");
    loading.center();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine both

```
function test() {
    var fbScrollTop;
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {
        fbScrollTop = info.scrollTop;
        alert(fbScrollTop);
    });
}
```

Comment: This alerts `undefined`. Any other idea?

Comment: Fixed. For unknown (to me) reason, everything you do with the info object should be inside the getPageInfo function.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Is it also possible to access the variable `fbScrollTop` outside of the function `test()`? Something like `test(); console.log(fbScrollTop)`

Comment: actually I couldn't find a way to use it outside of getPageInfo

Comment: same here and that is exactly what I need :-( But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods available in the SDK are *asynchronous* - this means that the response will not be available until the provided callback is invoked (with the response).